# Check if a ContentDialog is open or not

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a simple question. Since I can only have one `COntentDialog` open at a time and in the closing event of `ContentDialog` I have a condition that prevents the `ContentDialog` from closing by doing `args.Cancel = true`. So doing `ContentDialog.Hide()` can sometimes not close the `ContentDialog` and when opening a dialog again will cause an exception. 
Therefore, before any dialog, I want to be able to check if other dialogs are closed. How can I do that ?

Comment: This is a difficult question, if you have a lot of pop-ups, you can add a custom PopupService that checks your pop-up window before open second pop-up. All operations with pop-ups need to be encapsulated in this service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `Popup` control inside `ContentDialog`, you just need to locate it and then check its `IsOpened` property.

```
// Children method: https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/Continuity/blob/0cc3d7556c747a060d40bae089b80eb845da84fa/Continuity/Extensions/UtilExtensions.cs#L25
var popup = Dialog.Children().OfType<Popup>().Single();
var isOpen = popup.IsOpen;
```

Comment: Thx, Whether popup is null back.

Comment: @lindexi I don't think it can be `null`, but if you want to be sure, use `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: beyond answering my question, I found this method to be very useful.

Comment: doesn't work for me... there are no popups returned by Children() in my case and singleOrDefault throws.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the `IsLoaded` property is enough to check this, because it seems to be true if the dialog is opened and false if hidden

Answer (score 0):

I used Linq to check if a dialog is open:

Also, this is a repeat of [How to check if ANY ContentDialog is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996104/how-to-check-if-any-contentdialog-is-open/77602627#77602627)

```
using System.Linq;

var dialog = 
    VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current)
    .Where(p => p.Child is ContentDialog)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (dialog != null)
{
    // A dialog is open
}
else
{
    // Show my dialog
}
```