# How to check if ANY ContentDialog is open?

Tags: c#, uwp

So we can only have one opened content dialog at a time. This is fine. But in my app there are several possible content dialogs that can be opened, and I would like to avoid making my own variable because I can forget to add it somewhere and the whole app will crash (because trying to open second content dialog throws exception).

So my question is: How to check if **any** ContentDialog is open?

Note:

1. I don't want to check for specific ContentDialog.
2. I would like to avoid creating my own variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ContentDialog is shown in the PopupRoot so using `VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups()` will help you get it.

```
var openedpopups = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current);
foreach (var popup in openedpopups)
{
   if(popup.Child is ContentDialog)
   {
      //some content dialog is open.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tested accepted answer (by Vignesh) on target Windows 10 build 18362 and find that `ContentDialog` is never a child of popup. In my case simple check of the count works best:

```
    protected bool IsAnyContentDialogOpen()
    {
        return VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current).Count > 0;
    }
```

Please feel free to comment if there's any problems with this approach. Thanks.

Comment: This returns true when a MenuFlyout is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I used Linq to make this process a bit easier:

```
using System.Linq;

var dialog = 
    VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current)
    .Where(p => p.Child is ContentDialog)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (dialog != null)
{
    // A dialog is open
}
else
{
    // Show my dialog
}
```